# how to set default value for f.select rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to set default value using the the following code. The default value is not being set. What is wrong with this?

```
  = f.select(:on,Admin::DispatcherCondition.ons.collect {|p| [ p[0].humanize, p[0] ] },{default: @admin_dispatcher.on},{class: "form-control chosen-select"})
%td
  = f.select(:condition_type, Admin::DispatcherCondition.condition_types.collect {|p| [ p[0].humanize, p[0] ] },{:selected=> @admin_dispatcher.condition_type},{class: "form-control chosen-select"})
```

Comment: You have two `selects`.For which the `default value` is not being set?

Comment: for both of them it is not being set..

Comment: As you are using `simple_form`,try giving them as `f.input` instead of `f.select`.

Comment: tried... it is not working out

Comment: you could try setting the value of on in the instance in your view to whatever you want to be default...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
= f.select(:on,options_for_select(Admin::DispatcherCondition.ons.collect {|p| [ p[0].humanize, p[0] ] }, f.object.on),{},{class: "form-control chosen-select"})
```

`p[0]` must include a value which has `@admin_dispatcher.on` for default to be selected.

This works I just tried.

Comment: Apparently @admin_dispatcher is wrong. I made a stupid mistake there. I need it to be something like `@admin_dispatcher.dispatcher_conditions.pluck(:on)`. I am using pluck because that query will return multiple `dispatcher_conditions`. So this is stil not working anyway.